# How to convert string array to Big-integer array using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, biginteger

I have a String array and I want to convert it into BigInteger array using Java 8 streams.

```
String[] output = bigSorting(new String[]{"31415926535897932384626433832795", "1", "4900146572543628830293235422623540449026979", "10", "57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460", "5", 
                    "497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314", "57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314"});
        Object[] unsortedBigIntegerArr = convertFromStringArrayToBigIntegerArray(output);
```

This is what I have tried but I am not able to get BigInteger array, I am able to get the Object array though.

```
private static Object[] convertFromStringArrayToBigIntegerArray(String[] unsorted) {
        return Arrays.stream(unsorted).map(BigSorting2::convertFromStringToBigInteger).toArray();
    }

    private static BigInteger convertFromStringToBigInteger(String unsorted) {
        return new BigInteger(unsorted);
    }
```

Is there any way I can do it completely using Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
return Arrays.stream(unsorted)
             .map(BigSorting2::convertFromStringToBigInteger)
             .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);
```

Comment: Holy cow, this is wicked cool, thank you. Can you please suggest me best learning paths for Java8 streams.

Comment: Its still 7 minutes before I can accept your answer.

Comment: @pjj I'd start with Oracle tutorials really and the official documentation...

Comment: you could even do `.map(BigInteger::new)`

Comment: Anything else can I refer, which you found really helpful during your learning time?

Comment: @pjj I learned quite a lot from Stack Overflow questions and answers. Search for the [java-stream] tag, for example.

Comment: @pjj to be honest most people unfamiliar with the Java type system would expect your attempt of `Arrays.stream(unsorted).map(BigSorting2::convertFromStringToBigInteger).toArray();` to yield a `Stream<BigInteger>` but obviously this is not possible. due to a limitation of java one would have to explicitly specify an _array constructor reference_ to retrieve an array of the expected type hence the `.toArray(BigInteger[]::new);` in the answer.

Comment: @Aominè exactly what limitation are you talking about here?

Comment: @Eugene Since it is not possible to construct an array of a generic type `T`. For example `new T[x]` is an error since it will be erased to `new Object[x]` and that is a huge problem for library designers. the stream library solves the problem with an array constructor references or `toArray(s -> new BigInteger[s]);` in this particular case.

Comment: @Aominè almost good I would say, its not possible to create a generic array, but its possible to declare one. That is why a constructor reference is needed

Answer (score 0):

Something really simple like:

```
public void test(String[] args) {
    String[] output = new String[]{"31415926535897932384626433832795", "1", "4900146572543628830293235422623540449026979", "10", "57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460", "5",
            "497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314", "57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314"};
    Object[] bigIntegers = Arrays.stream(output)
            .map(BigInteger::new)
            .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigIntegers));
}
```

Comment: I think you mis-understood my question, please see my question or @Eugene answer, thanks for your answer though.

Comment: As I understood the question it was whether it was possible to get a `BigInteger[]` rather than an `Object[]` from the `String[]`.